# Mule ESB, Launching project encountered an issue after the project was renamed

Tags: eclipse, mule, project, esb

I have a flow running within a project named 'dm' that was created by someone else.
This flow works well.

I Right click and hit "Copy", and then I hit "Paste", and chose the project name 'dm_1'.  All looks well

So I try to run the new project, I right click on the flow and hit "Run As - Mule Application"

Immediately I get the following error:

```
Launching dm_1 has encountered a problem.

Studio has encountered a problem.  In order to get assistance with this issue, either contact MuleSoft or post a message in the MuleSoft Community Forums (http:/forum.mulesoft.org) with a detailed description of how you encountered the problem

DETAILS:

Studio has encountered a problem. In order to get assistance with this issue, either contact MuleSoft Support or post a message on the MuleSoft community forums (http://forum.mulesoft.org) with a detailed description of how you encountered the problem.

Project referenced by launch does not exist.
```

So how do I fix this problem.

I do not see anything within the xml that would suggest there is a project name that needs to be changed as well, with the possible exception of the following line:

```
<mulexml:schema-validation-filter schemaLocations="C:\Users\xxx\AnypointStudio\workspace\dm\src\main\resources\p.xsd" returnResult="false" doc:name="Schema Validation"/>
```

Where do I look to change the project name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding a new flow to the same project. Then right click on the new flow and run it. This will cause the entire project to run.